# Retrieve results from last 2 days from Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from only the last 2 days. For this I am inserting the date as a child of locations. This is what my database looks like:

[image]

As you can see, I'm inserting the date in the third level, as well as in the fourth level of data.

I tried using **.startAt(Date.now() - 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000);** but it did not work, as it is returning me **null** results.

```
readLocations = () => {
    // console.warn("readlocations called");
    allLocations = [];
    let locations = firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/locations")
      .child(this.currentUser.uid)
    .startAt(Date.now() - 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    locations.on("value", snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot)
    });
  };
```

This is how I'm inserting the data in the database.

```
  sendLocation = () => {
    // console.log("sending location log", this.props);
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/locations")
      .child(this.currentUser.uid)
      .child(Date.now())
      .set({
        uid: this.currentUser.uid,
        user: user,
        latitude: this.props.location.coords.latitude,
        longitude: this.props.location.coords.longitude,
        created_at: Date.now()
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you order your data before using startAt, endAt, equalTo.

See [Filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data) from the docs and the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#start-at)

> startAt() return items greater than or equal to the specified key or value,
>   depending on the order-by method chosen.

---

In your case you can use either [orderByKey](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#order-bykey) (3rd level) or [orderByChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#order-bychild) (4th level).

1. **orderByKey**

   ```
   const _2daysago = Date.now() - (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

   const query = firebase.database()
     .ref("/locations")
     .child(this.currentUser.uid)
     .orderByKey()
     // value must be a string (not a number)
     .startAt(String(_2daysago));
   ```

   > When startAt is used in combination with orderByKey(), the value must be a string.

   See [startAt - Parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#value:-number-%7C-string-%7C-boolean-%7C-null_2)
2. **orderByChild**

   ```
   const _2daysago = Date.now() - (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

   const query = firebase.database()
     .ref("/locations")
     .child(this.currentUser.uid)
     // no need to convert to a string
     .orderByChild('created_at')
     .startAt(_2daysago);
   ```

   Note: You'll a get a warning in the console encouraging you to define an index on created_at to improve performance (see [Indexing with orderByChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-child)).

You can try the above out on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-orderby?file=index.html). Just fork the project and add your Firebase config.